# How to get fb_ref back from Facebook custom Open Graph objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm having difficulty receiving the fb_ref with a custom Open Graph object.

Facebook's provided OpenGraph objects such as Article generate URLs that use a Facebook redirect (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?....) which then bring along the 'fb_ref' property that we are assigning to a token in order to track user origin. When a user shares such a link via the  setup and leaves a wall posting, it generates a share formatted like:

'Bob likes an article on Sitename'

...along with a URL that passes through FB and then to our site with the fb_ref property.

I'm noticing that if I create a custom object through Open Graph, when someone likes and wall posts something that I've configured as that object, it's formatted as:

'Bob shared a link'

...along with a bare URL to our site without the FB redirect nor the fb_ref parameter I'd like to use for metrics.

Is this a problem in my configuration or do all custom Open Graph objects behave this way on active Facebook shares (like + comment)?

Extra context: I can confirm through the FB Object Debugger that the incoming share is being recognized as my custom object, which leads me to believe this is expected behavior rather than a misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're testing your open graph links from "Recent Activity" on your Facebook profile and not "View Activity Log" (which strips params).

In pictures:

- Right place to look: http://imgur.com/vR3uyNE
- Wrong place to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAVMW.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are doing the same thing as I am, but it worked for me and my custom open graph action and object.

Here's a screenshot of a custom object with a custom action (Note, the link to my site includes my fb_ref param `fb_ref=123`. My app name is "ES1"):

[image: cog action and object with fb_ref param]

And that custom object with a like story (mouse hover over link reveals `fb_ref=123`):

[image: cog object like story]

My custom object:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="3814291xx" />
<meta property="og:type"        content="esmithy_one:bar" />
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.plooza.com/og/bar6.html?fb_ref=123" />
<meta property="og:title"       content="Bar Six" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Six drinking place" />
<meta property="og:image"       content="http://www.recipebits.com/media/food-icons/cookie-icon.jpg" />
```

My like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.plooza.com/og/bar6.html?fb_ref=123" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

You did not include your code that is generating your likes and OG actions, so I can't tell how you are generating the stories.